# Ionic 2 404 Not Found for URL

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an Ionic application, signed for Android. When I install the APK already-signed file using adb install (name).apk (the version in my computer), everything works. This is the signed-for-google version I am installing, and it works just fine.

As soon as the application is published on Android, and I download the exact same application from Google Play, it does not work, even if it is the same application I had installed manually before. I get 404 Not Found for URL when I try to sign up, and the same error when I try to log in. This server responds just fine if I install the APK version using adb install. How come it does not work when downloaded from Google play? 
It is calling the exact same URL.

I used my other Android phone to get the application from Google Play, and the same thing happened: 404 Not Found for URL

Comment: can you please post the log message ?

Comment: Might be some SSL or any other security related issue which is ignored in a debug app.

Comment: Response with status: 404 Not Found for URL https://spiela.co.uk/sign-up/app

Comment: The debug message is: W/SystemWebViewClient(15328): URL blocked by whitelist: https://spiela.co.uk/sign-up/app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I'm not an ionic developer but what I found is by default Cordova will put all external resources as black listed in production app which is a part of their security policy. You need to whitelist your URL.

Documentation of cordova's whitelist policy - https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/whitelist/

Plugin that can help you whitelisting your URL - https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/

Comment: that was exactly the issue. I just had to make changes to my config.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

This problem comes with latest version of cordova@8.0.0 & may be with 7.0.1 as well.

1. remove the android platform 
   ionic cordvoa platform remove android.
2. Downgrade the Cordova version to stable version.In my case I have done for.
   npm install cordova@6.4.0 -g

After that add android platform.

It works for me.

Hope this will help you out.